# Google plus-cmdline-sample

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I try to access my Google+ Account in Order to get my Data.
Now, I found the sample but it does not work properly...

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/plus-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/plus/cmdline/PlusSample.java?repo=samples):

My problem is in line 70!

If I try to run this program following Exception is thrown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:97)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:71)
at com.google.api.services.samples.plus.cmdline.PlusSample.authorize(PlusSample.java:70)
at com.google.api.services.samples.plus.cmdline.PlusSample.main(PlusSample.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

---

Now i tried the google-plus-java-starter project.

I registered on the console, got my client_id and client_secret and my API-key but now an exception is thrown.

```
Attempting to open a web browser to start the OAuth2 flow
Once you authorize please enter the code here: [entered myCode here]

============== Get my Google+ profile ==============

Okt 15, 2012 2:00:06 PM Sample getProfile
Schwerwiegend: {
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
}

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAsString(HttpResponse.java:464)
at Sample.main(Sample.java:45)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the Plus java starter examples available here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/

These include a command line example that should work.

Comment: maybe someone out there can help me.
I tried the plus java starter and an exception is thrown(see question above)

Comment: As the link in this answer is now deprecated, readers may wish to follow the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/java) which has a working example program.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the simple answer to your problem is on this cause:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

The Java Runtime is looking for `HttpServletRequest` class and can't find it in the classpath.

`HttpServletRequest` can only be found in Java EE framework (Servlet framework) and can only be invoked through a Web Container / Application Server (since it's a Servlet).

What you're trying to do is do an OAuth 2 dance, and in the dance, the service provider (the server whom you sent a request) does an HTTP redirect to your Web application. What I'm trying to say is that OAuth dance must be done as a web application.

To run your `Sample` as a standalone, you will, essentially, run a Servlet outside of the web container. This, essentially, means that you will have to write a HTTP layer that listens to port, translate the HTTP protocols in `HttpServletRequest` and be able to receive `HttpServletResponse` and populate back the HTTP response (see [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559295/can-we-have-servlets-outside-the-servlet-container-on-a-web-server)).

I don't know how the Sample link you've provided was run, but I'm pretty sure that a Servlet container was used (probably through a test case?)

Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Well I try to write a desktop application that should get the data from my Google-Plus account. I tried several methods now, but which is the right one? There was a Sample, that is now deprecated. See here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10

Comment: There is also a [not deprecated sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Installed_Applications).

Comment: The missing classes should be part of [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup).

Comment: The missing classes are not part of google-api-java-client.  I am also getting same error while executing the similar code.

Comment: I also obtained the `ClassNotFoundException` (for `HttpServletRequest`) when running the `calendar-cmdline-sample` code (link [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3)). The solution was to download servlet-api-2.5.jar. I have made a similar comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559206/theres-special-jar-to-add-for-javax-servlet-http-httpservletrequest/25559318#comment58844821_25559318).

Comment: I am getting this error some one tell me what it is.Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
 at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
 at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)