# there's special jar to add for javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest

Tags: java

I have a project that make use of Google Calendar API, in this PC I have configured tomcat and I can run it without problems, but when I try to run this on another PC I start getting a Exception, the other's PC doesn't have tomcat installed, because they're my clients PC's, the question is, do I need to install and configure tomcat even in the client's PC's? or Im missing a .jar to add to the classpath? I used a code to check the classhpath of the current project and all the jars are correctly in my 'lib' folder, What can I do?

this is the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
at control.GoogleCalendar2.authorize(GoogleCalendar2.java:132)
at control.GoogleCalendar2.<init>(GoogleCalendar2.java:54)
at Formas.Principal.<init>(Principal.java:37)
at Formas.Principal$11.run(Principal.java:376)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 20 more
```

and my classpath for this project is this:

```
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-android-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-gson-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-gson-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-java6-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-java6-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev76-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev76-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-gson-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-gson-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-java6-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-java6-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/gson-2.1-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/gson-2.1.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jackson-core-2.1.3-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/javax.mail.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jetty-6.1.26-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/transaction-api-1.1-sources.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/transaction-api-1.1.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/fluent-hc-4.3.4.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/httpclient-4.3.4.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/httpclient-cache-4.3.4.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/httpmime-4.3.4.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/lib/guava-17.0.jar
/Users/josemiguelledonnieblas/NetBeansProjects/capaPresentacion_expeDiente/build/classes/
```

I know there's a lot of jars, but when I downloaded the java class library for Google Calendar I just added all the jars to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing servlet-api jar. you don't need tomcat on their pc's unless they cannot access your PC's tomcat instance, and you want to run the server locally on their pc

Comment: I'm not using a tomcat instance on my pc, I'm installed it to another projects, but for this im using a rented server with BlueHost

Comment: in that case, you don't need tomcat at all. I'm guessing you have some tomcat libs in the classpath for PC's that have tomcat installed, but not for the client's PC's. Sounds like you are missing jars. Like servlet-api

Comment: I tried adding the servlet-api.jar, and it seems the problem disappear, but when I call some method that calls the webservice (hosted by blueHost) It doesnt do anything, I left my home, I'll do some test at the night

Comment: what kind of service? can you access the endpoint via HTTP? is there a way to prove that the service on bluehost is running and working correctly?

Comment: I was able to run the [Google Calendar API sample Java code](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/calendar-cmdline-sample) only after configuring [servlet-api-2.5.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar) on the build path. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521851/where-do-i-get-servlet-api-jar-from

Answer (score -1):

`HttpServletRequest` is part of the Java EE API and is provided by a servlet container such as Tomcat.  If your program is trying to do something with an `HttpServletRequest`, it means it expects to act as a web server and receive requests via HTTP.  If that's the case, then you need to run it in something like Tomcat — though it's unclear to me why Google's calendar client API would have servlets at all.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is building the request via java api

Comment: the Exception is thrown at the moment when I try to authorize the credentials to start working with the Calendar API, the rest of my program is about petitions to a bluehost server via json, so, do you think that I need to install tomcat on every pc?

Comment: `HttpServletRequest` is part of the *Servlet* API, which in turn is part of the EE API, but also available separately. Tomcat proves the point. It isn't a J2EE container.